# Spring Data MongoDB - Audit issue with unique index

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, unique-index

If the createdBy references to a document with unique indexes, it fails throwing *dup key* error.

**AbstractDocument.java**

```
public abstract class AbstractDocument implements Auditable<User, String> {

  @Version
  private Long version;

  @Id
  private String id;

  private User createdBy;

  private DateTime createdDate;

  private User lastModifiedBy;

  private DateTime lastModifiedDate;

}
```

**User.java**

```
@Document(collection = "users")
public class User extends AbstractDocument {

    private String name;
    private String surname;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String username;
}
```

**Book.java**

```
@Document(collection = "books")
public Book extends AbstractDocument {

     private String title;
}
```

Now, I have a script (Spring Batch) which initializes the db with some books. The script defines the auditor this way:

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoAuditing
public class MongoConfig {

   @Bean
   public AuditorAware<User> auditorProvider() {
      return new AuditorAware<User>() {

        @Override
        public User getCurrentAuditor() {
            User auditor = new User();
            auditor.setUsername("init-batch");
            auditor.setName("Data initializer");
            auditor.setSurname("Data initializer");

            return auditor;
        }
    };
  }
}
```

The script in somewhere does (for each book I need to persist) **bookRepository.save(book)**

The first book is persisted, but the second one throws:

*nested exception is com.mongodb.DuplicateKeyException: Write failed with error code 11000 and error message 'E11000 duplicate key error index: mydb.books.$createdBy.username dup key: { : "init-batch" }'*

Why? The unique index is for *users* collection, why is it checked for audit references?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867710/spring-data-mongodb-how-ignore-unique-indexed-field-when-document-is-embedded-i

Comment: thanks @titogeo ....so, it's not possible via spring/java annotations

Comment: Yes, even if it is an embedded document @Indexed annotation is going to apply for that field as well.

Comment: Ok, thank you...but I still can't understand WHY. I think that the correct behaviour should be like SQL tables, so the index should be applied at colleciton level, not at record level.