# Spring Data MongoDB: How ignore unique indexed field when Document is embedded in another one?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-mongodb

I have a Contract class defined like this:

```
@Document
public class Contract {

    @Id
    private String id;

    @Indexed(unique = true)
    private String ref;

    private String status = "pending";

    // getter & setter & hashcode & equals & tostring...
}
```

I want to save contract state over time, so I created a Version class like this:

```
@Document
public class Version {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private Contract contract;

    private Instant createdAt;

    // getter & setter & hashcode & equals & tostring...
}
```

When I try to save multiple times the version object over time, I have a duplicate keys exception. I think it's the duplicate key index on contract's ref which complains here.

How can I achieve this kind of thing?

Comment: Could you provide a little code snippet that shows off your issue? The way you've described your model, no exceptions should be thrown since the Contact object is nested inside the Version one, meaning that a contact in a version will be stored in the "version(s)" as a subdocument and the index on the "contact(s)" collection shouldn't matter.

Comment: I haven't write more than that. Just create two objects which one is nested in another one with a unique index on it and try to save two objects with the same underlying contrat and you'll have a duplicate entry exception.

Answer (score 10):

Simply add @Reference like this:

```
@Document
public class Version {

  @Id
  private String id;

  @Reference
  private Contract contract;

  private Instant createdAt;

  // getter & setter & hashcode & equals & tostring...
}
```

Comment: this actually works, but there is no word about it in the official spring data mongodb reference about it.

Comment: If I had any beer, I think I would owe you one for this trick, @VK321.  It does indeed work.  Too bad its missing in the documentation.

Comment: First it didn't work for me, but dropping a collection helped.

Comment: If you use Spring Data MongoDB and want to save only the id of the related object, which means you're normalizing your data model, I would choose the official `@DBRef` annotation. You can find more information in the [Reference Documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping-usage-references).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a way to achieve this from spring context.

The best way is to remove all the indices definition outside of your code.  i.e apply through an offline script. You can apply scripts using tools like [mongeez](https://github.com/mongeez/mongeez). It can be configured to run on application startup, so you can ensure its always run irrespective of location.

Once the application is live we might want to build new indices in a controlled manner. Having embedded in the code may not give this advantage as it will run only on startup.

If you are using offline scripts you are in total control.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use eventListener for index creation, So I use this code and sucessfully not creating index on the embedded documents, you can try this

```
@EventListener(ContextRefreshedEvent.class)
public void initIndicesAfterStartup() {

    MappingContext<? extends MongoPersistentEntity<?>, MongoPersistentProperty> mappingContext = mongoTemplate
            .getConverter().getMappingContext();

    IndexResolver resolver = new MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver(mappingContext);
    // consider only entities that are annotated with @Document
    mappingContext.getPersistentEntities()
            .stream()
            .filter(it -> it.isAnnotationPresent(Document.class))
            .forEach(it -> {
                var indexOps = mongoTemplate.indexOps(it.getType());
                resolver.resolveIndexFor(it.getType()).forEach(indexDefinition -> {
                    var indexHolder = (MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.IndexDefinitionHolder) indexDefinition;
                    if (StringUtils.isBlank(indexHolder.getPath())) {
                        indexOps.ensureIndex(indexDefinition);
                    }

                });
            });
}
```

The conclusion on this code

```
var indexHolder = (MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.IndexDefinitionHolder) indexDefinition;
```

var indexHolder = (MongoPersistentEntityIndexResolver.IndexDefinitionHolder) indexDefinition;

somehow indexHolder.getPath() on this field when we try to embed documents