# How to remove unique index on nested Object in Mongo

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot

I am using Spring Boot 2.0.0.M3. And I have the following object structure:

```
@Document(collections="note")
public class Note {
   String id;
   @Indexed(background=true,unique=true)
   String requestid;
}

@Document(collection="noteExpression")
public class NoteExpression {
  public static class Error {
    private DateTime dateTime = DateTime.now();
    private Note note;
    private String exception;
  }
  String id;
  //Some other fields
  Error error;
}
```

In the object of NoteExpression, I need to store the error information when something unexpected occurs. Everything seems to be fine. But the problem is Mongo will create a unique index for the nested property Note in NoteExpression.Error.

See the result of the Mongo command below:

```
>db.noteExpression.getIndexes()
[
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "key" : {
            "_id" : 1
        },
        "name" : "_id_",
        "ns" : "test.noteExpression"
    },
    {
        "v" : 2,
        "unique" : true,
        "key" : {
            "errors.note.requestid" : 1
        },
        "name" : "errors.note.requestid",
        "ns" : "test.noteExpression",
        "background" : true
    }
]
```

Unique index for requestid on the documents of Note is necessary in my system, but I don't want the unique index on the documents of NoteExpression. Is there any way to avoid creating the index on NoteExpression?

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB indexes include the nested (and of course also the referenced) documents by design. It is often a headache and the only solution that I have found until now is to implement the uniqueness constraint by coding it in the save/insert operations, so you have to query the database first, check the preconditions, and then save/insert if the preconditions are met. I will investigate it further to see if Spring-Data provides some workarround for this.

Comment: Refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47830677. Using a @Reference on Nested Object helps