# How to avoid Spring Data MongoDB @CompoundIndexes creates indexes on nested fields

Tags: mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I tried to add compound index for the collection called answersheet:

```
package my.package;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.CompoundIndex;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.CompoundIndexes;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Data
@Document
@CompoundIndexes({
        @CompoundIndex(def = "{'testId':1, 'userId':1}", unique = true)})
public class Answersheet extends Base {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private String id;
    private String testId;
    private String userId;
    private String status;
    private Long updatedAt;
    
    private List<Answersheet> version = new ArrayList<>();

    private List<Answersheet> draft = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

But it results in creating not only one compound index,
but also two compound indexes for nested field version and draft:

```
db.getCollection("answersheet").createIndex({
    testId: NumberInt("1"),
    userId: NumberInt("1")
}, {
    name: "testId_1_userId_1",
    unique: true
});
db.getCollection("answersheet").createIndex({
    "version.testId": NumberInt("1"),
    "version.userId": NumberInt("1")
}, {
    name: "version",
    unique: true
});
db.getCollection("answersheet").createIndex({
    "draft.testId": NumberInt("1"),
    "draft.userId": NumberInt("1")
}, {
    name: "draft",
    unique: true
});
```

Can someone help me to prevent it creates compound indexes for nested answersheet-typed fields?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `org.springframework.data.annotation.Reference` annotation.

```
@Reference
private List<Answersheet> version = new ArrayList<>();
```

See this related question: [Spring Data MongoDB: How ignore unique indexed field when Document is embedded in another one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36867710/spring-data-mongodb-how-ignore-unique-indexed-field-when-document-is-embedded-i)